# Shell in C with multiple commands, segmentation fault(core dumped)

Tags: c, shell

I am trying to write a basic shell in C for ubuntu. I want to execute several commands in one line , seperated with semi colon. I m trying to run it but i get the message "Segmentation fault (core dumped)"

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include  <sys/types.h>
#ifdef _WIN32
#include <windows.h>
#define chdir _chdir

#else
#include <unistd.h>
#endif

#define MAX_LENGTH 512


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  char *cmd;
  char line[MAX_LENGTH];
   char *token[20];
int i=0;
int j=0;
int k=0;
char* args[20];

  while (1) {
    printf("8334>");
    if (!fgets(line, MAX_LENGTH, stdin)) break;



    while ((cmd = strtok(line, ";")) != NULL)
    {
        printf("<<%s>>\n", cmd);
        strcpy(token[i], cmd);
        i+=1;
        cmd = NULL;
    }

    for(j=0;j<i;j++){
    k=0;

    while ((cmd = strtok(token[j], " ")) != NULL)
    {
        printf("<<%s>>\n", cmd);
        strcpy(args[k],cmd);
        k+=1;
        cmd = NULL;
    }
    args[k]=NULL;

     pid_t  pid;
     int    status;

     if ((pid = fork()) < 0) {     /* fork a child process           */
          printf("*** ERROR: forking child process failed\n");
          exit(1);
     }
     else if (pid == 0) {          /* for the child process:         */
          if (execvp(args[0], args) < 0) {     /* execute the command  */
               printf("*** ERROR: exec failed\n");
               exit(1);
          }
     }
     else {                                  /* for the parent:      */
          while (wait(&status) != pid)       /* wait for completion  */
               ;
     }


    for(int l=0;l<20;l++)
    args[l]=NULL;



    }
}return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your debugger will be most helpful here. You don't know how to use a debugger ? Then it's time to start learning.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding, 1) consistently indent the code.  indent after every opening brace '{'.  unindent before every closing brace '}'.  2) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  Consider a closing brace as a separate statement.  3) variable names should indicate content or usage (or better, both).  Variable names liie `l` give no such information.

Comment: when the parameters to `main()` are not going to be used, then use the signature: `int main( void )`

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding, separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a single blank line

Comment: the posted code contains some 'magic' numbers.  I.E. 20.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis.  Suggest using `#define` or `enum` statements to give those magic numbers meaningful names,  Then use those meaningful names throughout the code.

Comment: when outputting an error message, it should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout` (suggest using `fprintf( stderr, ... )` for this operation.

Comment: this statement: `while (wait(&status) != pid) ;`  is rather 'iffy'  Suggest using `waitpid( pid, &status, [options]);` as the posted code can then check for successful execution of the child so that on a failure of the child, will not start executing any following commands

Comment: The posted code is missing the needed headers for the `wait()` function.  Suggest adding: `#include <sys/types.h>` and  `#include <sys/wait.h>`

Answer (score 1):

The main thing that I see is that you do not reserve space for copying strings to  `args[i]` and `token[i]`; you are reserving space for an array of pointers, but not for the content to which the pointers shall point:

```
char *token[20]; // reserves place for 20 pointers
...
strcpy(token[i], cmd);  // token[i] has not been initialized...
```

The probably easiest way to overcome this is to write

```
token[i] = strdup(cmd);
```

instead of `strcpy`; note that `strdup` automatically reserves enough memory for holding the copy, whereas `strcpy` expects that this space has already been reserved before.

Anyway, do not forget to free this memory once not used any more, and do not forget to do this also for `args`.

There might be other issues in the code as well; for example, when using `strtok`, only the first call will pass the line to split, whereas all consecutive calls should pass `NULL` then (see doku). But I think this is then at the level where you and your debugger can get ahead :-)

Answer (score 0):

the root of the problem is this line:

```
strcpy(token[i], cmd);
```

This is trying to copy that string to an entry in `char *token[20]`  But, that is just an array of pointers, not an array of pointers to strings.

perhaps you could use:

```
token[i] = strdup( cmd );
```

Of course, the code would then need to check (!=NULL) `token[i]` to assure the call to `strdup()` was successful AND after using a specific command, pass that pointer to `free()`

similar considerations apply to the `char *args[20];` usage